# How to fill a input field from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this has been driving me nuts, im looking for a solution that will fill a input field from what ever selection is made from a drop down.

My current working solution (that does not include a drop down) is as follows :

```
<form method="link" action="dualstream/index.html">
<input value = 'apolloz' name="stream1" placeholder="" required="required"    
autofocus="autofocus" />

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Click to watch the stream" />
</form>
```

So that auto fills the text field with "apolloz" then when you press submit it takes you to the relevant page which uses the word apolloz.

Im looking for a solution that you can select the streamer from a drop down list, select it and that option fills the text field, and you can then submit.

Im sure this is javascript based as i have seen similar things which use numerical values.

Sorry if this is a bit vague, but any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the value is in the `select` anyway, why do you need to copy it to the `stream1` field? Just put the `select` within the form and give it the name `stream1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<form method="link" action="dualstream/index.html">
<input value = 'apolloz' id="txt" name="stream1" placeholder="" required="required"    
autofocus="autofocus" />
<select id="mySelect" onchange="selectionchange();">
    <option value="abc" >abc</option>
    <option value="xyz" >xyz</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Click to watch the stream" />
</form>
```

and add following javascript function

```
function selectionchange()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById('txt').value = str;
}
```

Comment: raza / kingkero, thats spot on works near exactly how i want it to, had to make a change to the id in the form so the first box doesn't change on selection (but i only just realized i wanted it that way) thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple, if you use jquery you can do this

```
$(function(){
    $("#your_select").change(function(){
        $("#your_input").val($('#your_select option:selected').val())
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `selectbox #selectid` then,

```
 $("#selectid").live("change", function() {  <br> 

 $("#stream1").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));  <br>

});
```

Answer (score 0):

u can also do this using just javascript
on the onchange function of your select u can call a function that will put the selected value in your input
like

```
<select id="element1" onchange="pickvalue()"/>
<option>asad </option>
<option>asad2 </option>
</select>
```

and your pickvalue function can look something like this

```
function pickvalue()
{
document.getElementById('yourinputid').value = document.getElementById('element1').value
}
```